# Access nested JSON property in jspdf autotable plugin

Tags: jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I have just started using jsPDF and the AutoTable plugin, and it is almost perfect for what we are using it for.  One question...

Is it possible to assign a dataKey in the columns definition to a nested property within the JSON that is being mapped to the table?

We have a JSON structure that looks like this:

```
"Primary_Key": "12345",
"Site_Name": {
  "Address_Name": "Address 1"
  },
"Default_Screen_Name": "Bob",
"Full_Name": "Bob Smith"
```

If we use the following columns:

```
var columns = [
  { title: "ID", dataKey: "Primary_Key" },
  { title: "Screen Name", dataKey: "Default_Screen_Name" },
  { title: "Full Name", dataKey: "Full_Name" }];
```

Everything works perfectly.  However, we would also like to do something like the following:

```
var columns = [
  { title: "ID", dataKey: "Primary_Key" },
  { title: "Iterations", dataKey: "Iterations" },
  { title: "Screen Name", dataKey: "Default_Screen_Name" },
  { title: "Site Name", dataKey: "Site_Name.Address_Name" }];
```

Where we are using `Site_Name.Address_Name` to index into the nested JSON object to retrieve the value.

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not at the moment. You can follow that feature request [here](https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable/issues/258). Your options are currently to either flatten the data before passing it to autotable or use the hooks to extract the specific text you want. That can be done like this:

```js
var columns = [
    {title: "ID", dataKey: "id"},
    {title: "Name", dataKey: "name"}, 
    {title: "Country", dataKey: "address"}
];
var rows = [
    {id: 1, name: "Shaw", address: {country: "Tanzania"}},
    {id: 2, name: "Nelson", address: {country: "Kazakhstan"}},
    {id: 3, name: "Garcia", address: {country: "Madagascar"}}
];

var doc = jsPDF();
doc.autoTable(columns, rows, {
   didParseCell: function(data) {
       if (data.column.dataKey === 'address') {
           data.cell.text = data.cell.raw.country;
       }
   }
});
doc.save('table.pdf');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf@1.3.3/dist/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf-autotable@2.3.1/dist/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>
```

**Update** for additional question in comments:

```
var columns = [
    {title: "Country", dataKey: "address", displayProperty: "country"},
    ...
];
var rows = [...];

...

didParseCell: function(data) {
   if (data.column.dataKey === 'address') {
       var prop = data.column.raw.displayProperty;
       data.cell.text = data.cell.raw[prop];
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the very quick answer!  I think your suggestion will work perfectly for what we need.  I have subscribed to the GitHub issue for future changes as well.

Comment: Is it possible to provide additional information in the column definition, so that we don't have to hard code the "country" property into the createdCell function?  Thanks!

Comment: You can now in version 2.3.2 access the column definition in `column.raw` similar to cells and rows. Added an example in the answer highlighting how this could be used. I think that is what you wanted.

Comment: If I could up vote an answer again I would! That is exactly what I needed, thank you!

Comment: @SimonBengtsson Doesn't work anymore, run the code snippet.