# How to display nested JSON in jspdf angular8

Tags: angular, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

My requirement to download date in PDF format. Except nested JSON remaining elements are populated in PDF. Nested JSON displayed as {Object Object}. I tried lot of solutions suggested in internet haven't found solution.

Can anyone give me the suggestion.

jspdf, angular8

The columns which are displayed in PDF

```
 var columns = [
            {title: "ID", dataKey: "id"},
            {title: "Name", dataKey: "name"}, 
            {title: "Country", dataKey: "address"}
        ];
```

The content which is displayed in PDF, columns and rows are mapped using dataKey.
Id and Name both are single elements in JsonArray but the address field is a nested JsonObject. I am trying to access the address.country but it is not displaying.

```
        var rows = [
            {id: 1, name: "chakri", address: {country: "Tanzania"}},
            {id: 2, name: "hari", address: {country: "Kazakhstan"}},
            {id: 3, name: "venki", address: {country: "Madagascar"}}
        ];
```

id, name values are populated but address is nested JSON country files is not populating in pdf instead in place of country it is showing [object
Object]

```
    exportPdf() {
                import("jspdf").then(jsPDF => {
                    import("jspdf-autotable").then(x => {
                        const doc = new jsPDF.default(0,0);
                        doc.autoTable(this.columns, this.rows);
                        doc.save('primengTable.pdf');
                    })
                })
            }
```

Comment: You can convert the JSON to String before populating it in PDF. Try  `JSON.stringify(_YourJsonObject_)` and then try passing this to PDF conversion.

Comment: Hi Karthik, I have updated my question. Can you please check once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some more research and using [Access nested JSON property in jspdf autotable plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44133030/access-nested-json-property-in-jspdf-autotable-plugin?rq=1) as a guide, I came up with a solution that gets the country property.

JSFiddle to see it work: https://jsfiddle.net/mu4v06dh/1/

```js
var columns = [
    {title: "ID", dataKey: "id"},
    {title: "Name", dataKey: "name"}, 
    {title: "Country", dataKey: "address", displayProperty: "country"}
];
var rows = [
    {id: 1, name: "Shaw", address: {country: "Tanzania"}},
    {id: 2, name: "Nelson", address: {country: "Kazakhstan"}},
    {id: 3, name: "Garcia", address: {country: "Madagascar"}}
];

var doc = jsPDF();
doc.autoTable({
 body: rows,
  columns: columns,
  didParseCell: function(data) {
   if (data.column.raw.displayProperty) {
     var prop = data.column.raw.displayProperty;
      var text = data.cell.raw[prop];
      if (text && text.length > 0) {
       data.cell.text = text;
      }
   }
}
});
doc.save('table.pdf');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf@1.3.3/dist/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf-autotable@3.2.11/dist/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created an example in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68180024/4754308). for short: a parent cell must be cleared and the height set during didParseCell and the new table must be added as extra content during didDrawCell