# Nested Table in jspdf

Tags: javascript, angular, pdf, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I am developing a table using jspdf.
I try to put autotable in autotable.
The problem is that the row of the table is not dynamically adjusted to the height of the inserted table.
Then it overlaped to the next row.

here is my code.

```
doc.autoTable({ html: '#table', 
                      theme:'grid', 
                      overflow: 'linebreak',
                      bodyStyles: {lineColor:[0, 0, 0], 
                                   textColor:[0, 0, 0]}, 
                                   startX: 15, 
                                   startY: 50, 
                                   styles:{font:'noto'}, 
                                   headStyles : { halign: 'center', 
                                                  textColor: [0, 0, 0], 
                                                  fillColor:[255, 255, 255], 
                                                  lineWidth: 0.1, 
                                                  lineColor:[0, 0, 0]
                                                },
                      didDrawCell: function (data) {
                        if (data.cell.section === 'body' && data.column.index === 1 && data.row.index === 9) {
                          
                          document.getElementsByClassName("confluenceTable")[0].id = 'confluenceTable';
                          console.log("------test----")
                          console.log(document.getElementById("confluenceTable"))
                          data.cell.text = "";
                          doc.autoTable({
                                          html: '#confluenceTable', 
                                          theme:'grid', 
                                          overflow: 'linebreak',
                                          bodyStyles: {lineColor:[0, 0, 0],
                                                        textColor:[0, 0, 0]
                                                      },
                                          styles:{font:'noto'},
                                          startY: data.cell.y + 2,
                                          margin: {left: data.cell.x + data.cell.padding('left')},
                                          tableWidth: 'wrap',
                                        })
                        } 
                      },                     
                       didParseCell: function (data) {
                        if (data.cell.section === 'body' && data.column.index === 1 && data.row.index === 9) {
                          data.cell.text = "";
                        }
                      },  
                      // , columnStyles: {0: {fillColor: [212, 212, 212]}, tableLineColor: [0, 0, 0]}
                      });
```

and here is my results
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Before you create the nested table you must set the minimal height of the parent cell in the didParseCell event and clear the content. And add the nested table as extra content in the didDrawCell event.

This is an example with an HTML table and nested table in one cell. The height calculated is using the assumption that the rows are all equal height. (typescript)

```js
...
  this.yPos = 0;
  this.createAutoTable(myTableNode, { startY: this.yPos + 20 })
...
 
  /**
   * create the autotable with the plugin
   */
  private createAutoTable(tableNode, tableStyle = {}): void {
    this.autoTable(this.doc, {
      ...tableStyle,
      html: tableNode,
      // event that can be used to override content or styles for a specific cell
      didParseCell: data => {
        const rawNode = data.cell.raw as HTMLTableCellElement;
        const nestedTable = rawNode.querySelector('table');
        if (nestedTable) {
          this.prepareCellForNestedTable(data.cell, nestedTable);
        }
      },
      // event to add additional cell content
      didDrawCell: data => {
        const rawNode = data.cell.raw as HTMLTableCellElement;
        const nestedTable = rawNode.querySelector('table');
        // if there is a nested table draw that table
        if (nestedTable) {
          const subTableStyle = {
            html: nestedTable,
            startY: data.cell.y + 4,
            margin: { left: data.cell.x + 4 },
            tableWidth: data.cell.width - 4
          };
          this.createAutoTable(nestedTable, subTableStyle)
        }
    });

    // @ts-ignore
    this.yPos = this.doc.lastAutoTable.finalY + 10;
  }

  /**
   * if there is a nested table inside a cell then clear the content and set the height of the cell
   */
  private prepareCellForNestedTable(cell, nestedTable: HTMLTableElement) {
    cell.styles.minCellHeight = this.getTotalRows(nestedTable) * 11; // calc how many rows are needed?
    cell.text = [];
  }

  /**
   * Count total rows of nested table for calculating the height of primary table (assumption 1 row height cells)
   */
  private getTotalRows(table): number {
    return table.querySelectorAll('tr').length;
  }
```

This is html rendering:
[image]

This is pdf result:
[image]

Comment: Can you also share JavaScript version of the above code solution. Thanks

Comment: I think y only need to remove the type settings and private/ public and y have native javascript nog typescript